# Hardware and Service for Voip

Tags: voip, webserver

What king of hardware/service do I need to create a voip system in my LAN ( only PC-to-PC call and without internet connection !! ) ?

1) Internet Connection

2) Voip phones
...

.

Help me to compile the above list ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Skype is a quick and easy way to get up and running with VOIP.

However, there are other things you can run like Asterisk server and have VOIP enabled phones, but is fairly advanced and requires a lot of time. It depends on what your goal is. Are you in a business, or just two roomates looking to chat from two floors?

Comment: It's a college project. I have to create a simple voip system ( without skype ) for calling pc-to-pc in my lan without internet ;).
So do I have to buy an asterisk server ?
Thanks ;)

Comment: Not exactly, you just need a server to run it on. http://www.asterisk.org/

Comment: or use a VM. Maybe you can find a virtual appliance / preconfigured VM for that use?

Answer (score 0):

PC - to - PC?

Why don't you use headsets and Skype or any SIP-compatible Client & Service?

**[edit]**

After telling us that skype is not an option you should go for Asterisk and evaluate if it's any use for you. Here are some virtual appliances i found using google:

http://www.vmware.com/appliances/directory/48

http://www.jumpbox.com/app/asterisk

AFAIK the hardware needn't be that strong for a simple setup. If you are working with a lot of clients (or active "telephone lines") you may need a bigger machine. But i'm just guessing and adding some bits of knowledge here.

Comment: Could you tell me some SIP-compatible server for this issue ;) ?

Comment: Please have a look here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_SIP_software

One prominent example ist Asterisk [sic], but i don't know if it really fits you needs (to much...?).

Comment: @lajuette: check @xRobot's comment on @Kevin's post...that'l clarify why he can't use skype.

Comment: That comment was posted after my answer. Couldn't know that.